# CQ/AEM - What are the 'resource' in a CQ form component?

Tags: aem, web-component, sling

I'm trying to understand how CQ form components works. 
I see that they use a variable called 'resource' a lot. For example, in the beginning of every componenet it always goes:

```
final String name = FormsHelper.getParameterName(resource);
final String id = FormsHelper.getFieldId(slingRequest, resource);
final boolean required = FormsHelper.isRequired(resource);
```

I know that Sling treats everything as a resource. But what exactly is this specific piece of 'resource'? Where is it defined? Where does it come from? And what does it contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resource variable, which is an implementation of `org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource`, is an object that represents a node entity in the jcr repository, but comes with some additional convenience methods compared to e.g. lower level `javax.jcr.Node` object.
In this case the mentioned resource likely represents the component's resource.

To explain why sling is using the terminology Resource:

A resource is a fundamental concept in restful APIs. 
Resources are typed objects with associated data, relationships to other resources and  methods that operate on it.

Sling is actually a restful layer on top of a Java Content Repository. 
For the sling layer the repository is a virtual tree of resources.
I highly recommend you to read the official documentation for more details on this topic https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/resources.html

Comment: Note that while JCR is the primary persistence for Sling, there are definitely other resource providers, see https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/accessing-filesystem-resources-extensions-fsresource.html and https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/nosql-resource-providers.html .